# How does decimation work without losing samples?

Tags: decimation

For example, changing the frequency from 32.768Mhz to 2kHz there is a scale down of 16384.

From the algorithms I've seen you have to discard 16384-1 samples and only count the 16384th sample. However, that many samples being lost will lose important parts of the information.
How does decimation work then?

**EDIT**

A signal is sampled at 2kHz and then modulated with a carrier wave of signal frequency 8.192MHz which is sampled at 32.768MHz. I am trying to revert it back to 2kHz, by decimation. I assume pass it through a LPF and  apply decimation however, the points sampled at 32.768MHz are then lost?

Comment: You need to clarify what is the signal spectral content, and what is the sampling rate.  I *assume* you mean that "the frequency" is the sampling rate, and you're changing it from 32.768MHz to 2kHz.  If this is the case, please *edit your question* to reflect that.  While you're doing that, please comment on the spectral content of the signal you're interested in -- does it have components at frequencies above 1kHz, or is its spectrum limited to 0-1kHz?  Again, if that's the case, edit your question.

Comment: @TimWescott Hopefully the edit clears it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure why you accepted my other answer seeing your updated question, but here we go:

What you want to do is *passband subsampling*. You need to understand what *aliasing* is: For every frequency $x$ in the output nyquist bandwidth $[-f_{sample, out}/2,+f_{sample, out}/2]$, the decimation "moves a copy" (that's what we call "it aliases") of every frequency component at $n\cdot f_{sample, out}, \quad n\in \mathbb Z$ from the original bandwidth.

Usually, in decimation, you want that to *not* happen, so you block out all but the target bandwidth with a low-pass filter.

In band-pass subsampling, you block out everything but the target band-pass region. So, you're using aliasing to move your signal by an integer multiple of your output sampling rate. Done!

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct. You need to make sure the information content fits into the output rate, and that implies your signal needs to be band-limited to 1/16384. Otherwise you'll lose information.

Making sure that's the case with a filter is called anti-alias filtering.

Comment: In addition to this, I see that now the minimum sampling rate that can reproduce a 32.768Mhz signal is the 16Mhz. Therefore lowpass filter would work. But the sampling rate is 16Mhz, how can decimation now lead to producing a sampling rate of 2khz?

Comment: Check your math.  The absolute minimum sampling rate that can reproduce signal that is strictly 32.768MHz wide is 65.536MHz -- and in practice, the sampling rate would need to be higher.

Comment: @TimWescott Yes you're right. It should be double the max frequency. However, I still don't understand. For decimation 65.546MHz/2kHz signals are now skipped to obtain the new the sampling frequency, and yet to that means more signals are lost?

Comment: again, yes, decimation means throwing away samples. That's it's purpose, @kepsek. You can only do that if you know that it's going to work out. Reasearch anti-aliasing, it'll become clearer.